# Finding a Certified Image for Devices Certified with a Custom Image

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04, dell, xps, certification

So I have a Dell XPS 13 Plus, which I planned to dual-boot with Windows and Ubuntu 22.04. The plan was to purchase the version with the paid OS (Windows) and then install the free OS (Ubuntu).

However, this device was certified for Ubuntu 22.04 using a custom image, not the standard image. So now I need to find that custom image.
https://ubuntu.com/certified/202112-29801

Dell's support channels have been worthless when it comes to finding this custom certified image. Are there other ways to find it? Does Ubuntu have a repository where they store custom images that were used for certification purposes? I suspect the answer is no, but might as well ask...

Comment: Only Dell has the customized image that they use on their computers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe these images can be acquired from Dell using the OS Recovery tool. [This article](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/da-dk/000132294/how-to-use-the-dell-hosted-recovery-image-of-linux?lang=en) describe how to do it.

However, it seems the recovery image itself can only be unpacked on Windows (which is rather silly if you ask me). From browsing through the articles I haven't been able to find a link to download the Recovery tool ISO directly - if anyone finds this, it would be a big help.

So it would seem (from what I can gather so far) that you need a Windows computer to generate the USB image (where you can select Ubuntu), and then you can install the custom Dell Ubuntu image.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like there is a good generic answer here, but I learned something interesting in chatting with Dell support (assuming this is correct): apparently they use a stock 22.04 image from Ubuntu's website, and they don't perform any special post-installation steps.

My hypothesis for is that for a Dell XPS 13 Plus, a "custom image" may simply mean that the "Install third-party software..." option was checked during installation.

Comment: They have their own OEM kernel